# Нагрузочное тестирование WS сервера

Tags: java, websocket, netty, нагрузочное-тестирование

В данный момент разрабатываю WebSocket сервер, реализующий модель "издатель - подписчик" (то есть, сервер только отсылает информацию клиентам, не принимает запросы). Написан на Netty, ориентирован на максимальную производительность - логики минимум, только роутинг данных по подписчикам. В идеале, сервер должен легко держать нагрузку в 80К-100К подключений.

Вопрос заключаются в том, каким образом можно протестировать сервер под нагрузкой? Сама идея проста: открыть 100К WS подключений и начать лить данные (сервер является прослойкой, имеется полный контроль входящего потока данных). Клиенты только принимают инфу, ничего не отсылают, и мне нужно проверить, какой толщины поток данных сервак сможет раздавать на эти 100К клиентов. 
Но я не представляю, какими инструментами пользоваться для открытия стольких соединений? Что можете посоветовать? И так, чтобы можно было добавить клиентам логики -  высчитывать задержку между отправкой данных серверу, и их приёмом клиентами.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы посоветовал вам использовать [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), он и создан с целью проведения нагрузочного тестирования.

Как конкретно его (тестирование) провести - вопрос к вам и вашему приложению. Однако подобные вещи с помощью JMeter делаются и программируются достаточно просто.

Comment: А осилит ли он 100К подключений?

Comment: 100к активных юзеров или 100к TCP-подключений?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator читайте описание вопроса. 100K WS соединений. Клиенты только принимают инфу, ничего не отсылают, и мне нужно проверить, какой толщины поток данных сервак сможет раздавать на 100К клиентов.

Comment: @ЯниславКорнев а вам в теории никто не запрещает развернуть кластер из JMeter`а (смотрите статью https://habrahabr.ru/company/dataart/blog/273967/). Поэтому какую нагрузку позволит вам сгенерировать ваш компьютер/сервер/кластер, такая и будет. Само собой, такой инструмент ест не мало памяти...

Comment: @EvgenyLazarev Посмотрел JMeter. Понял, что он мне совершенно не подходит, ибо он для более сложных и комплексных задач. Нерациональное использование ресурсов тестовых машин. В целом, написал на том же Netty NIO-клиент, который осиливает 60К подключений на инстанс (память не мерил, но сжирает намного меньше JMeter-а). Не знаю, почему сразу не пришло в голову (да и не думал, что на нём можно клиент написать, это уже друг посоветовал).